# Saltstack file.manage_file not finding the source file

Tags: salt-stack

I am running the command

```
salt-ssh 'my-vm' file.manage_file /home/file.txt '' '{}' salt://file.txt '{}' root root '700' '' myenv ''
```

But i get the following error message

> comment:
> Source file 'salt://file.txt' not found

N.B that when putting this in a state file and running apply state there is no error and the file is placed on my-vm as expected

Salt master has the configuration

```
file_roots:
  myenv:
    - /srv/salt/states/base
```

and my file.txt lives in

```
/srv/salt/states/base/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.manage_file` is an execution function, not a state, and not designed for direct use. For example, it requires `file.get_managed` to have been called first.

To manage a single file from the command line, use the [`state.single`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.single) function:

```
salt-ssh 'my-vm' state.single file.managed name=/home/file.txt source=salt://file.txt saltenv=myenv
```

Comment: i still get the same error

my-vm:
----------
          ID: /home/file.txt
    Function: file.managed
      Result: False
     Comment: Source file salt://file.txt not found in saltenv 'myenv'
     Started: 09:53:49.219469
    Duration: 45.369 ms
     Changes:

Comment: Then what is the state that you say works, and how are you running it?

Comment: This might be a case of [this bug](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/21370), in which case add `--extra-filerefs=salt://file.txt`.